# Wepback --watch sees the change but doesn't recompile output file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using `npx webpack --watch`. When I first run it, it shows many messages with suffix:

```
[built] [code generated]
```

Then when I do a change in `Data.js` file it shows:

```
[...]
./src/swagger/data.js 3.55 KiB [built] [code generated]
[...]
```

Until now everything is going as expected. Webpack detected change, recompiled files and put them in the `/dist` directory.

When I do second change to the `Data.js` file however, it shows that webpack compiled successfully but it doesn't show `[code generated]` message and it won't work until I restart `npx webpack --watch`. Code in `/dist` directory contains **old data**.

Basically now it's stuck in a state in which it detects changes but doesn't recompile changed files. Any idea how to force it to recompile this?

I tried adding this to my webpack config but it acts just the same

```
watchOptions: {
  aggregateTimeout: 600,
  ignored: /node_modules/,
},
```